# I want to boot from USB using ISO file

Tags: networking, boot

I downloaded bootable USB tool and copied Windows 8 to USB.

But i want to change boot priority. When i enter to BIOS i have four options like
CD/DVD
HardDisk
Floppy
Ethernet

Which one should i change to priority 1 ro boot from USB??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this is offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

Some older computers don't support booting from USB. You can burn some software to a CD to boot from the CD which will then let you boot from USB. Here's a link to a [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/boot-from-a-usb-drive-even-if-your-bios-wont-let-you/) on howtogeek.com that will help you.